# Problems with Spring Security 4 and REST, does not display HTML files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with my proyect, I've tried to configure Spring Security 4 with Spring REST, but there is a problem when I try to access with any context.

Here  is my project structure:

[image]

Inside of "views" are my html pages.

And here is my spring configuration.

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-business.xml"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<security:http auto-config="true" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />

    <security:form-login  login-page="/iniciar_sesion"
                 username-parameter="email"
                 password-parameter="password"
                 authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" />
    <security:csrf/>

</security:http>
<context:component-scan base-package="turing.solutions.dy.web" >
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*\.(.)*"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="security"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="turing.solutions.dy.web.security.CustomUserDetailService" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        10
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And this is my RestController:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage() {
    System.out.println("Redirect");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value="iniciar_sesion",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String iniciarSession(ModelMap model){
    model.put("login", "log");
    return "iniciar_sesion";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, Object> login() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("login", "ok");
    return map;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "accessDenied";
}

private String getPrincipal() {
    String userName = null;
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        userName = principal.toString();
    }
    return userName;
}

}
```

Ant this is my CustomUserDetailService

```
@Service("customUserDetailService")
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UsuariosService usuariosService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String correo) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Usuarios usuario = this.usuariosService.findByCorreo(correo);
    if (usuario == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("El usuairo " + correo + " no existe, favor de verificar");
    }
    return new User(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getPassword(), usuario.getActivo(), true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(usuario));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Usuarios usuario) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Roles rol : usuario.getRolesList()) {
        System.out.println("Usuario " + usuario.getEmail() + " ROl" + rol.getDescRol().toUpperCase());
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + rol.getDescRol().toUpperCase()));
    }
    return authorities;
}
}
```

When I try to access to the URL "http://localhost:9080/DespreocupateYA/home" I see this

[image]

But I should see this

[image]

So,my question is: Why i can't see the html pages in my project? I've searched and I found many Spring configurations, but I've not been able to solve the problem.

My Server is an Apache Tomcat 8.0.28.

I hope you can help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `@RestController` annotation to `@Controller` and it will work properly.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)  are docs explaining the difference between this two annotations

Morover when you say RestController you mean a Controller wich  handle some data like JSON objects. Here you need a simple Controller to handle html views.

**EDIT**

You didn't mention what kind of view rendering engine you are using, this is example configuration for jsp

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And this to your spring conifguration file, make sure you declare `"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` name space so you can use bean definition

Comment: Thanks for your help Oskar. I have tried to add InternalResourceViewResolver and it doesn't work yet u.u ... Do you have other idea?

Comment: @xXxbravocecxXx does it still returning plain 'index' text?